# Apply css styles specific to screen resolution

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-resolution

How do i apply styles for differnt screen resolutions

For example: I have a computer with max screen resolution of **1366 X 768** 
and want to specify css styles only for this resolution .

Css @media rules only take into consideration min-width and max-width of the browser how do i target for specific resolution.

[image]

Comment: what is your targeted specific resolution?

Comment: Some where around ~1560 approximately

Answer (score 1):

Use the resolution tag i.e. :

```
@media (resolution: 150dpi) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

More explantations and syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1366px)
              and (min-height: 768px) and (max-height: 768px) {
    /* style */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `width` and `height` mediaqueries

```
@media (width: 1366px) and (height: 768px) {
   :root { background: yellowgreen; }
}
```

to match a viewport of `1366x768` px

> [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMVYEg)

Anyway it's worth noting that, unless you are in fullscreen mode, that rule won't be applied because the UI of your browser takes some room, so the actual viewport can't be exactly the same of the chosen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) and (max-width: 1600px){
    /*Your style */
}
```